# "На квартире" и "в квартире"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, предлоги

Всех с днём Победы!

Очевидно, что вариант "в квартире" во многих случаях будет правильным. Но когда его можно заменить на "на квартире" и какие будут нюансы смысла?

Не знаю, как сейчас, но у классиков XIX века часто встречается последний вариант, причем не только про съёмную квартиру, но и словосочетание "на своей квартире", смотрите в [Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CmQqLAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKILqraGxqboDMglncmNyZWF0ZWRABWoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBAUItCisKKQoDcmVxEiIKINC90LAg0YHQstC%2B0LXQuSDQutCy0LDRgNGC0LjRgNC1MAE=).

Comment: И тебя, Артём, с **П**раздником! Чегой-то, мне кажется, ты плюсиков давно не раздавал. Разве нет достойных вопросов-ответов? P. S. А ты свой, как говорит Галина Аванесова, лови!

Comment: Спасибо, Рим! Да я и не читал особенно никаких обсуждений. Ничего интересного давно не видел. :(

Comment: Интересно, а почему на вопрос никто не отвечает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ответ как версия**

Предлоги В и НА (в квартире и на квартире) определяют объект как имеющий **внутреннюю структуру** (предлог В) и как объект **в обобщенном понимании** (предлог НА). К примеру, мы говорим «на Урале» (на территории) и «в Сибири» (в области с различными территориальными зонами).

**В современной** речи квартира – это конкретный объект с определенным строением, обычно в частной собственности, поэтому мы чаще говорим «в квартире».

**Но раньше это было не так**. Собственник строил многоквартирный дом и сдавал квартиры внаем. Тогда чаще жили на съемных квартирах, переезжая с места на место. Это была **временная территория**, поэтому говорили «на квартире».

При наличии местоимения «своя» имелось в виду какое-то противопоставление, например: «***На своей квартире** изволил принять он дворянство и представителей купечества»*. (Вероятно, в квартире, а не в учреждении.)

Интересно посмотреть, насколько часто в современной речи используется сочетание **«на квартире»**, но это в плане для подробного ответа. Надеюсь **на ваше активное участие**, я же ограничусь именно версией.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Пээса не понял, это вы о себе? Или о чём это вообще? Актёры не справлялись с рол**ями**, думаю, нет? "Нельзя" — "не раз" мне как-то режет слух... Поделюсь, кстати, тем, как родился этот вопрос. Я записывал аудиосообщение двоюродному дяде из Севастополя и сказалось так: *у бабушки с дедушкой на квартире.*

Comment: Да, обо мне. У бабушки с дедушкой на квартире? Здесь ничего странного для предлога НА, так как имеется в виду не помещение, а территория, пространство (как бы мир, в котором живут бабушка с дедушкой).

Comment: А зачем вы первый комментарий удалили? На самом деле я многого там не понял) что-то грузинское было)

Comment: Артем, заметаю следы... :) Я довольно часто удаляю то, что кажется мне лишним. Слишком откровенным, например. Меня насмешил комментарий про грузинскую школу, а потом началась дискуссия... А ведь не хотела ничего говорить. Это я к тому, что "носило меня, как осенний листок".   https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473942/Слово-накопленный-какой-корень

Comment: Странно, а я слышал анекдот про сол и фасол (тот же, только другие слова). Да, отличная песня Ножкина "Я в весеннем лесу"! Меньше года назад фильм этот смотрел. ;)