# Слово накопленный, какой корень?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Наш учитель по русскому говорит что у слова накопленный корень коп, а в интернете везде написано что копл, можете объяснить почему так?

Comment: Бывает два "корня" - этимологический, то есть собственно сам корень, который коп(копить, копна, накоп и скорее всего связан с копать - ударять/бить, то есть накопления - это результат некоего активного однотипного действия, однако не имеющего четкого представления о том к чему собственно стремимся, в отличие от собирать, копал-копал и накопал - накопил), и семантический или морфемный, то есть тот, который выделяют ногой. Так что не нужно задавать глупых вопросов, почему тут такой "корень" - патамучта.

Comment: Вспомнил анекдот: "В грузинской школе учитель ведет урок русского языка: Дэти, русскый язык- очэн сложный язык. Напрымэр: слова мол и шмел - пышутся с мягким знаком, а слова вилька и тарелька - бэз! Дэти, этого нельзя объясныть, это нужно запомныть!" В такие моменты я чувствую себя учеником в грузинской школе.

Answer (score 3):

Корень копл-, это результат йотовой палатализации (смягчение согласных в результате воздействия [j]). В слове "копить" корень коп-, а в коплю - копл-. Получается такое чередование в корнях.

Губные б, п, в, м + j = бл, пл, мл, вл (люблю, капля, дремлю, ловля)

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, почему это "результат йотовой палатализации (смягчение согласных в результате воздействия [j])". Если можно, своими словами, чтобы всем было понятно.  Ведь если непонятно, то эту информацию приходится запоминать (как в грузинской школе:)

Comment: Мне просто кажется, что для школьного уровня вполне достаточно знать, что есть некий термин, с помощью которого объясняется, почему корень чередуется, и запомнить несколько слов с такой разновидностью чередования. Кому нужно больше - погуглят сам термин. А потом - как в анекдоте о Ходже Насреддине. Пусть, кто знает, расскажет тому, кто не знает. :) Но вообще есть хорошее компактное видео на эту тему: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-3wNXlpa3A

Comment: спасибо, непременно посмотрю. Но я бы все-таки привела в ответе полезную информаццию о причине чередования. А про существование термина можно сказать проще:  это результат исторических изменений в русской фонетике.

Comment: Всё равно не очень понятна логика приляпывания пусть и сонорной, но все-таки сонорной согласной к корню. То есть БЛ, ПЛ, МЛ, ВЛ - это один звук? Пусть даже так, как эта информация помогает связать это с корнем который, например КОП? Ведь это один и тот же корень, то есть смысловая основа? Или вообще для чего нужна эта информация, ну пусть останется где-то в разделе языковых фишек фонетики, зачем её тащить в корни?

Comment: Я читала в каком-то школьном учебнике информацию на эту тему. Кажется, там говорилось о фонетической надставке Л, которая добавляется  к корню перед  гласными Е, Ю (каплет, треплют), но ее нет перед А (капает). Это полезная информация, так как в разговорном варианте ее пропускают, а это ошибка (пишут и говорят "сыпет" вместо сыплет).

Comment: @Sharon Нет, это интересно, я не спорю, но та же грамота: "Оба варианта возможны. Засыплет – строгая норма, засыпет – допустимый вариант (разговорный, но встречается и в письменной речи)." То есть логика, что очень желательно, но не обязательно, потому что смысла это не прибавляет.

Comment: @Sharon нацкорпус ищет сыпет, например, у Лескова: "мороз по снегу самоцветным камнем сыпет", - ну и там еще есть от классиков - Шолохов, Лермонтов...

Comment: Сыплет черемуха снегом (Есенин). Но вы правы, обе формы сейчас допускаются, Это я посмотрела в орфоэпическом словаре Резниченко (2010). Правда, до сих пор считала, что это единственная форма, разрешенная на письме.